# Python regex extract number between forward slashes

Tags: python, regex

New to python and need help with regex please.

How do I extract the number  `10000000000` from the string below

```
/s-seller/John/10000000000/time/1
```

Please note the word `John` is dynamic and number `10000000000` can also be any random numbers.

Thank you

Comment: That string contains two separate numbers.  How do you decide which one do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

line = "/s-seller/John/10000000000/time/1"

m = re.search(r'/(\d+)/', line)

print(m.group(1)) # 10000000000
```

the regex expression `r'/(\d+)/'` you can use.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the first number:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('.*\/(\d+)\/.*')
regex.match(your_str).group(1)
```

the `(\d+)` is a capture group that will match your number.

---

A simpler approach without regexes would be to split the string by `/`:

```
[int(d) for d in your_str.split('/') if d.isdigit()]
```